# what is solution for error "Saw a form start tag, but there was already an active form element. Nested forms are not allowed. Ignoring the tag"

Tags: html, forms, jsp, w3c-validation

I am using nested forms on jsp

```
<c:forEach items="${facetData.topValues}" var="facetValue" varStatus="status">
  <form action="#" method="get" id="${status.index}">
    <input type="hidden" name="q" value="${facetValue.query.query.value}"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="text" value="${searchPageData.freeTextSearch}"/>
    <c:if test="${not empty facetValue.name }">
    <div class="checkbox_div">
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" ${facetValue.selected ? 'checked="checked"' : ''}  onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit();"/> 
    </div>
      <span class="facetcheck">
      ${facetValue.name}
      </span>
    </c:if></form>
</c:forEach>
```

If I see the rendering form from firebug(inspect elements) it will show all attributes of form directly (form tag will not be there) and check the page source from front-end it gives me only 1st form marked in red saying:`Saw a form start tag, but there was already an active form element. Nested forms are not allowed. Ignoring the tag.

Please give me suggestions to resolve this issue.

this is the source code :

```
                <ul class="filters_ul">
                <li>
                        <form action="#" method="get">
                                <input type="hidden" name="q" value=":relevance:interest:yoga-pilates:category:balance-stability-training"/>
                                <input type="hidden" name="text" value=""/>
                                <div class="checkbox_div">
                                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"   onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit();"/>
                                </div>
                                    <span class="facetcheck">
                                    Balance & Stability Training</span>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                <li>
                        <form action="#" method="get">
                                <input type="hidden" name="q" value=":relevance:interest:yoga-pilates:category:functional-strength-training"/>
                                <input type="hidden" name="text" value=""/>
                                <div class="checkbox_div">
                                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"   onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit();"/>
                                </div>
                                    <span class="facetcheck">
                                    Functional & Strength Training</span>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                </ul>
```

Only for 1st form it is showing red merk if i see this in right click > view page source from firefox.

Comment: do you have another <form> element on page beside what you've pasted?

Comment: "Please give me suggestions to resolve this issue"... I think you'll find that two of us already have

Comment: Shay Elkayam = yes i have another <form> also

Comment: @Laxman, we have given you suggestions, and I have tried to explain exactly what the error message is telling you.  If you want to ignore that advice and wait for another answer (which will tell you the same thing, or something that is likely to be incorrect) then you are welcome to do that... and as a result, you will still have your error.  We are not paid to be here, we do not have to try and help you - so when people do try to help, don't dismiss it. Good luck with working it out - I will not be continuing

Comment: @freefaller Thanks for your contribution. I am new here.Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

An HTML document can contain multiple `<form>` elements... **however** they cannot be nested within each other.

For example the following is allowed...

```
<form action="this.aspx" method="get">
</form>
<form action="that.aspx" method="get">
</form>
```

But this is **not** allowed...

```
<form action="this.aspx" method="get">
  <form action="that.aspx" method="get">
  </form>
</form>
```

From what you've put, it looks like your code is already contained with a `<form>` element

Comment: i need multiple forms so using form loop.from is inside for loop. only 1st form is getting error else are being submit properly.
my code is like 

<c:forEach items="${facetData.topValues}" var="facetValue" varStatus="status">
  <form action="#" method="get" id="${status.index}">
    <input type="hidden" name="q" value="${facetValue.query.query.value}"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="text" value="${searchPageData.freeTextSearch}"/>
   
</c:forEach>

Comment: @Laxman, I'm not sure how repeating your code in an unreadable format is going help me.  If you have another `<form>` that ALL your code lives within, then you will get the error.  Look at the **rendered** HTML that is sent to the browser, search for `form` tags, and make sure they're not nested

Comment: i have checked page source. I don't have <form> inside the <form> :

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late entry but I found something weird and thought of sharing with others. I had the same issue and I HAD to use only nested forms. After some hit and try method I provided a fake form tag inside the main form tag. The browser only ignores the first nested form tag and rest of the tags are compiled normally. Having said that the below code works fine for me

```
<form id="MainForm">
   <form> </form>
   <form id="FirstForm">

   </form>
   <form id="SecondForm">

   </form>
</form>
```

In the above code the first form gets ignored while the second and third one gets compiled and very well used with jquery validator.